# Sorting item variations from Etsy

Tags: python, sorting

(MY FIRST POST)
I looked through similar questions asked and surprisingly couldn't find anything that matched my problem.

I am looking for the best way to sort variation data for my wife's mask making etsy store. She has many fabric colors each with small, medium and large sizes.

I have successfully used the split function to break the given 'Variation' column into 'color' and 'size'

I am here today asking what might be the best/most efficient way to structure this data from here.

for example;

color(1)       #_small: 2
#_medium:3
#_large: 1

color(2)       #_small: 1
#_medium:4
#_large: 2

etc.
or maybe some other way
I assume some other business does a similar thing for their incoming orders and I would love to implement it for my wife's store as well.

My code so far is:

```
import pandas as pd
etsy = pd.read_csv(r"full_path.csv")
etsy['color'] = etsy.Variations.str.split(',', expand=True)[0]
etsy['size'] = etsy.Variations.str.split(',', expand=True)[1]
print(etsy[['color', 'size']])
```

This method was used to avoid "key must equal columns error" because customers were able to write personal comments in another variation section, which often contained commas.

current results of `print(etsy[['color', 'size']])`  are

```
                  color               size
0            Color:Black     Size:Adult M/L
1            Color:Black      Size:Adult XL
2        Color:Fern Grey   Size:Adult Small
3       Color:Blue Birds         Size:Adult
4  Color:Purple Hexagons  Size:KIDS (4~9yo)
```

Comment: What's the purpose for the sort?  Is this for displaying the items?

Comment: Post the current sample output of `print(etsy[['color', 'size']])`.

Comment: Tangential, but if commas are screwing up the parsing of your CSV file, it's not correctly formatted CSV.

Comment: Which category of size is small, medium and large?

Comment: The purpose of this sort is to help speed up the process, I cut fabric for her often while she makes the masks. One of us always has to manually search through each order and write a tally sheet of each color and size by hand. We are both very busy people and I wish to automate the process. the peak in a month was 500 orders, the real issue is that she has about 30 fabric colors available.

Comment: You want to assign one of the `{small, medium, large}` to each mask, but in dataset  you have sizes like `Adult M/L, Adult Small`... how would I know `Adult M/L` is small or medium or large?

Comment: sorry, actually the sizes are adult M/L, adult XL, Adult Small, and adult (which is a different style of mask altogether). I was using small, medium and large as an example

Comment: I should have been more accurate from the beginning, I will do better in the future

Comment: the code you wrote earlier was great! I can easily substitute in my sizes

Comment: @JesseHolliday I have undeleted the answer but I couldn't figure out where you need to do the sorting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with Amit Vikram Singh's help I came up with the following code that printed out each color needed and how many of each size was required with .groupby and .agg

but before I ran that code I filtered the data for orders only on a specific date.

Thank you to everyone who assisted me!!

the final code was as follows:

```
etsy_sale_date = df[df['Date'].str.match('sale_date')]

from collections import Counter
etsy_size_color_date = etsy_sale_date.groupby('color')['size'].agg(Counter)
print(etsy_size_color_date)

[output]
color
Color:Colorful Cats                              {'Size:Adult (M-L)': 1}
Color:Green                                     {'Size:Kid (4~9 yo)': 1}
Color:Grey                                       {'Size:Adult Small': 1}
Color:Hunter Green     {'Size:Kid (4~9 yo)': 1, 'Size:Adult Small': 1...
Color:LF Pink                                    {'Size:Adult Small': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.groupby('color')['size'].agg`, inside aggregate you can use `Counter` to create dict of size and its count.

```
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue','blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red'], 'size': ['small', 'medium', 'small', 'medium', 'medium', 'large', 'small', 'medium','medium','medium','medium', 'large', 'large']})

>>> df
   color    size
0   blue   small
1   blue  medium
2   blue   small
...
10   red  medium
11   red   large
12   red   large


>>> df.groupby('color')['size'].agg(Counter)
color
blue    {'small': 2, 'medium': 3, 'large': 1}
red     {'small': 1, 'medium': 4, 'large': 2}
Name: size, dtype: object
```

Comment: 4   Color:Purple Hexagons  Size:KIDS (4~9yo)
..                    ...                ...
91   Color:Circle Monster  Size:KIDS (4~9yo)
92    Color:Blue Big Star  Size:KIDS (4~9yo)
93     Color:Blue Flowers       Size:Toddler
94    Color:Orange Leaves   Size:Adult (M-L)
95          Color:LF Pink      Size:Adult XL

Comment: @JesseHolliday Code didn't work in this case?

Comment: I could not try the code tonight, It is late here, I am getting ready for work early in the morning. I apologize for my forum etiquette btw...This is what prints out under color and size. the store has about 30 fabric colors to choose from, also the sizes I listed above plus KIDS (4~9yo), also one called Toddler. I don't know if there is a way to sort by colors without having to write each color into the code itself. if it has to be done I will do it though.

Comment: @JesseHolliday I have just given output for sample input. You can run `etsy[['color', 'size']].groupby('color')['size'].agg(Counter)`